# 3 buttons change between actions and images

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

i have 3 buttons that all have an image and action. However when the centerButton is pressed they should all change action and image. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var centerButton: UIButton!


override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    centerButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#4834B4")
    centerButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.centerButton.frame.width / 2
    centerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(centerButtonClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightButtonClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightButtonClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)




}

func centerButtonClicked() {
    if !pictureTaken {
        //change action
    } else {
        //change action
    }



}
```

Comment: Show us what did you try

Comment: action means..?

Comment: i've added some code that i've made, however i was wondering whether there was something smarter ? this is in a UIView Subclass

Comment: What do you mean by action here?

Comment: i mean like what function to be called when button is pressed / what code to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have known well you want something like this:

```
func leftButtonClicked() {
    if centerButton.backgroundColor == UIColor.yellowColor() {
        centerButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    } else {
        rightButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    }

}




func centerButtonClicked() {
   if leftButton.backgroundColor == UIColor.yellowColor() {
        leftButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    } else {
        rightButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    }
```

I write two actions with an image changement.